# Looping through ansible dictionary to assign dictionary values

Tags: dictionary, ansible, yaml, ansible-inventory

Is there a way to loop through an ansible dictionary to assign other ansible dictionary values?

I have the following in my group_vars/all:

```
domain_controllers:
  dc0:
    hostname: "dc0"
    ip_address: "192.168.1.0"
  dc1:
    hostname: "dc1"
    ip_address: "192.168.1.1"
  dc2:
    hostanme: "dc2"
    ip_address: "192.168.1.2"
```

I have a generic keepalived role that configures keepalived that a server role uses to make a VIP for these domain controllers.

The following is my `roles/servers/forward/vars.yml` which the keepalived role uses to build the keepalived.conf file.

```
virtual_server:
  - virutal_server_ip: "192.168.1.10"
    virtual_server_port: 389
    ...
    real_servers:
      - real_ip: "192.168.1.0"
        real_port: 389
        description: "dc0"
        ...
      - real_ip: "192.168.1.1"
        real_port: 389
        description: "dc1"
        ...
      - real_ip: "192.168.1.2"
        real_port: 389
        description: "dc2"
        ...

  - virtual_server_ip: "192.168.1.10"
    virtual_server_port: 636
    ...
    real_servers:
      - real_ip: "192.168.1.0"
        real_port: 636
        description: "dc0"
        ...
      - real_ip: "192.168.1.1"
        real_port: 636
        description: "dc1"
        ...
      - real_ip: "192.168.1.2"
        real_port: 636
        description: "dc2"
        ...
```

I already have the jinja formatting in the keepalived role to build `/etc/keepalived.conf` based on these variables.

What I want to do is assign these variables based on the contents of the `domain_controllers` dictionary. How could I use `set_facts` to assign a large nested dictionary like this?

I would like to just loop through `domain_controllers` because I would like to just update my `group_vars/all` when I upgrade and/or migrate to new DCs since I also have other playbooks that use this variable.

Additionally is is possible to assign these variables in `vars/main.yml` rather than through a `set_facts` task?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the following:

In group_vars/all:

```
domain_controllers:
  - ip_address: "192.168.1.0"
    hostname: "dc0"
  - ip_address: "192.168.1.1"
    hostname: "dc1"
  - ip_address: "192.168.1.2"
    hostname: "dc2"
```

And in my vars file I called the list with:

```
virtual_server:
  - virutal_server_ip: "192.168.1.10"
    virtual_server_port: 389
    ...
    real_servers:
      - real_ip: "{{ domain_controllers.0.ip_address }}"
        real_port: 389
        description: "{{ domain_controllers.0.hostname }}"
        ...
      - real_ip: "{{ domain_controllers.1.ip_address }}"
        real_port: 389
        description: "{{ domain_controllers.1.hostname }}"
        ...
      - real_ip: "{{ domain_controllers.2.ip_address }}"
        real_port: 389
        description: "{{ domain_controllers.2.hostname }}"
        ...

  - virtual_server_ip: "192.168.1.10"
    virtual_server_port: 636
    ...
    real_servers:
      - real_ip: "{{ domain_controllers.0.ip_address }}"
        real_port: 636
        description: "{{ domain_controllers.0.hostname }}"
        ...
      - real_ip: "{{ domain_controllers.1.ip_address }}"
        real_port: 636
        description: "{{ domain_controllers.1.hostname }}"
        ...
      - real_ip: "{{ domain_controllers.2.ip_address }}"
        real_port: 636
        description: "{{ domain_controllers.2.hostname }}"
        ...
```

The downside to this is that the playbook errors if there aren't at least 3 items in `domain_controllers`. I would still like to find a way to loop over the list.